# ASP.NET MVC - 404 Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a view folder structure:

> - Views
> - Admin
> - Post
> - New

and routing is defined with:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin", // Route name
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But, for ex: /Admin/Post/New gives 404 error. Because It doesn't go to Admin folder first.

Err:
The view 'New' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Post/New.aspx
~/Views/Post/New.ascx
~/Views/Shared/New.aspx
~/Views/Shared/New.ascx

How I can define the folder?

Comment: Do you also have matching controllers for your views? Also, what's with the underscored in front of the view paths?

Comment: Yeah I have controllers. Underscores are just for to show the subs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating subfolders like that under `Views`, take a look at [Areas](http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-areas/). This may better help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.  The web.config file in the /Views folder prohibits any views being accessed directly.  Users won't be able to visit www.yoursite.com/Views/___Admin.

I'd rename them back to /Admin, /Post, /New etc.

Otherwise, you need to create a new ViewEngine (you can extend the WebFormsViewEngine) to supply the additional paths.